# How to mitigate error "kernel: nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet"

Tags: debian, networking

We recently had a problem with one of our servers (Debian Squeeze) becoming unresponsive during heavy-ish load.  Looking at the kernel logs, I think this is the cause:

```
kernel: nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet
```

As I understand it, this is the conntrack module, which does some stateful tracking of connection, reporting that the table used to store the connection details is full.

From the research I have done, there seem to be two ways to mitigate this:

1. Increase size of the table.
2. Remove the module from the system altogether.

However, neither `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_conntrack_max`nor `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/netfilter/ip_conntrack_max` exist on this machine (there is no `ipv4` catalogue  under `net`).

If I do `lsmod` I get no results.

So, I'm a bit confused - perhaps someone could clarify the situation for me?

- Is conntrack installed?  If so, where are the settings? And why doesn't it show up in lsmod?
- If conntrack is not installed, what is issuing the table full messages?

Thank you

Comment: Really? `lsmod|grep conntrack` doesn't yield results? Maybe you're using IPv6?

Comment: Right, `lsmod|grep conntrack` comes back empty (as does lsmod on it's own).  Definitely using ip4, although both ip4 and ip6 are configured on this server - it's a virtualized server if that makes any difference.

Comment: I have `nf_conntrack_max` directly in `/proc/sys/net` and in `/proc/sys/net/netfilter`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on servers running with Ubuntu 18.04. Even though the `nf_conntrack` module was not loaded at startup, later during traffic spikes, messages were dropped (`nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet`).

I'm not aware of a way to disable the functionality, but I ended up explicitly loading the module, so I could overwrite the table size.

First, make sure that `nf_conntrack` gets immediately loaded by including it in `/etc/modules`:

```
nf_conntrack
```

Then increase its table size, which otherwise will depend on the memory size of the server, by overwriting the defaults in `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max=262144
net.nf_conntrack_max=262144
```

To verify:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max 
262144
```

As said, it was tested on Ubuntu 18.04, but I would expect it to work also on Debian.

For some further background, why `nf_conntrack` might get later loaded, even if it is not present after booting up, [this related answer](https://serverfault.com/a/676721/151221) has an example where the module gets automatically loaded when `iptables` is called. Adding it explicitly to `/etc/modules` eliminates that kind of complexity.